# How could Father Duré survive as a person on the Tesla tree?

Tags: hyperion-cantos, dan-simmons

(I am presently halfway through The Rise of Endymion, it may of course be explained in what I have not read yet)

In "Hyperion", we read the story of Father Duré who after leaving the Bikura crucifies himself on a Tesla tree and afterwards "but it still looked like Paul Duré" ... "seven years. Living. Dying ... the cruciform ... forcing him to live again"

Did he get a cruciform v 2.0 that made it possible to be resurrected without the personality and intelligence going away as had happened to the Bikura, or is something else going on there since he obiously did not end up that way?

Comment: Have you read The Fall of Hyperion? It is explained there how father Dure survived. Unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: yeah, I've read Fall of Hyperion, but I never understood how he could not end up as a "Bikura zombie".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Father Duré did get an improved version of a cruciform that avoided all the nasty effect of multiple resurrections, thus why he didn't 'devolve' like the Bikuras.

I haven't read the books in a long time, so I may get some details wrong but, basically, the TechnoCore learned from their errors with the Bikuras and managed to improve the cruciform by using them as a mean to transfer all the information about the wearer into the Void Which Binds.

As far as I remember, they never fully explained what kind of improvements were made to get rid of the degeneration that happened to the Bikuras.

Comment: I have only read through the Fall of Hyperion. In that book, when Duré is resurrected, we mentions that while he is still somewhat smart, he is no longer as sharp as he was before. How is this consistent with Duré having an improved cruciform that kept his mind intact?

Comment: That's how Duré felt, based on nothing else but his feelings. It could be only a psychological thing: he felt less sharp because he 'knows', from having seen the Bikuras, that each passing resurrections will make him less sharp. Except that he has no way to know that he's been implanted with an improved cruciform. Besides, when he resurrect from Lenar Hoyt, after tens of thousands of resurrections on the Tesla tree, he's still quite sharp.

Comment: I'm not sure *anyone* has been resurrected as many times as Duré, though. Even a vastly improved cruciform that leaves you *almost* as good as before will, over many generations, result in noticeable degradation. The typical person might be resurrected once every few decades. Duré was probably resurrected at least once a week for 7 years. If one resurrection leaves you at 99.99% capacity (whatever that means), 364 resurrections leaves you at under 70% (.9999**(52*7)).

Comment: I seem to remember that Duré did mention, at some point, that he felt diminished intellectually somehow after having been resurrected so many times, even though he couldn't point out exactly what had 'diminished'.